# UPTADE em php, não estou conseguindo

Tags: php

Sou iniciante em php e estou tentando fazer um CRUD... no botao editar eu fiz uma funcao em js para aparecer os inputs e redirecionar para editar.php?id=echo $row['id']; Porém ele apenas pega o ULTIMO id cadastrado..

## CRUD - ALUNOS

Aluno
        Nota
        Turma

```
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($listarAlunos)){
            $id = $row['id'];
            $nome = $row['nome'];
            $nota = $row['nota'];
            $turma = $row['turma'];
    ?>
        <td>
            <?php echo"$nome"?>
        </td>
        <td>
            <?php echo"$nota"?>
        </td>
        <td>
            <?php echo"$turma"?>
        </td>
        <td>
            <button onclick="abrirEditar()">Editar</button>

            <a href="remover.php?id=<?php echo $row['id'] ?>">
            <button>Remover</button>
            </a>
        </td>
        <tr></tr>

        <script type="text/javascript">
        function abrirEditar(){
            var div = document.getElementById("divEditar");
            div.innerHTML = "<br/><form method='post'>";
            div.innerHTML+= "Novo Nome:<input type='text' name='novoNome'/><br/>";
            div.innerHTML+= "Nova nota:<input type='text' name='novaNota'/><br/>";
            div.innerHTML+= "Nova Turma:<input type='text' name='novaTurma'/><br/>";
            div.innerHTML+= "<a href='editar.php?id=<?php echo $row['id'] ?>'><input type='submit' value='editar'/></a>";
            div.innerHTML+="</form>";
        }
        </script>
    <?php
        }
    ?>
    <div id="divEditar"></div>
    </table>
</body>
```

editar.php

```
include 'conexao.php';
$id = $_GET['id'];
$novoNome = isset($_POST['novoNome']) ? $_POST['novoNome'] : '';
$novaNota = isset($_POST['novaNota']) ? $_POST['novaNota'] : '';
$novaTurma = isset($_POST['novaTurma']) ? $_POST['novaTurma'] : '';

echo $id;
$sql = "UPTADE tbaluno SET nome = '$novoNome', nota = '$novaNota', turma = '$novaTurma' WHERE id = $id";

$editarAluno = mysqli_query($conexao, $sql);
```

Answer (score 1):

Olá pode ser problema na montagem do sql, tente assim:

```
$sql = "UPDATE tbaluno SET nome = '" . $novoNome . "', nota = '". $novaNota ."', turma = '" . $novaTurma . "' WHERE id = " . $id;
```

Coloque o script para fora do while e da seguinte forma:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function abrirEditar(id){
        var div = document.getElementById("divEditar");
        div.innerHTML = "<br/><form method='post'>";
        div.innerHTML+= "Novo Nome:<input type='text' name='novoNome'/><br/>";
        div.innerHTML+= "Nova nota:<input type='text' name='novaNota'/><br/>";
        div.innerHTML+= "Nova Turma:<input type='text' name='novaTurma'/><br/>";
        div.innerHTML+= "<a href='editar.php?id="+ id +">'><input type='submit' value='editar'/></a>";
        div.innerHTML+="</form>";
    }
    </script>
```

E o editar da seguinte forma:

```
  <button onclick="abrirEditar(<?php echo $row['id'] ?>)">Editar</button>
```

Comment: Não eh isso :( , o problema eh que ele pega o ultimo id cadastrado, ele até edita, porém edita o ultimo

Comment: n deu certo :d.

Answer (score 0):

Gustavo, pelo que eu entendo está faltando logo no começo do seu código já declarar que haverá a opção de uso do id. Já faça a declaração da conexão e do id logo no começo, depois, sempre que usar a busca pelo id, será o mesmo. Se estiver usando SESSION melhor ainda, pois pode declarar essa busca de id através da SESSION. 
Exemplo:

```
$id = $_SESSION['db_login']['id'];
```

Comment: Ou essas ações:

<a href="read_one.php?id=" . $linha['id'] . "'>
 <a href="read_one.php?id=<?php $_SESSION['db_login']['id'] ; ?>

Comment: Qual é o erro que tem apresentado? Mas, tente essas ações que eu indiquei.

Answer (score 0):

Olá Gustavo Tudo bem? então... eu recomendaria voçe a ultilizar esta função de tabela apenas com php e html, ate mesmo pelo fato assim como eu de ser iniciante, abaixo possui um codigo que pode lhe ajudar, basta replicar.

Conexão.php

```
$conn = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);

if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

mysqli_set_charset($conn, 'utf8');
```

USERS.php

```
<thead>
        <tr>
          <th>#</th>
          <th>Nome</th>
          <th>Nota</th>
          <th>Turma</th>
          <th>Actions</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <?php
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id DESC");
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){ ?>
        <tr>
          <td><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row['nome']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row['nota']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row['turma']; ?></td>
          <td>
            <a href="edit.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" class="btn btn-info btn-xs">
            <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Edit
            </a>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
      <?php } ?>
```

Edit.php

```
if (isset($_POST['enviar'])) {

    $id      = $_POST['id'];
    $nota    = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['nome']);
    $nota   = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['nota']);
    $turma = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['turma']);

    $sql = "UPDATE `users` SET `nome` = '$nome',`nota` = '$nota',`turma` = '$turma' WHERE `id` = '$id'";
    $ssl = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    header("Location: USER.php");
    exit();
}
```

Recomendo que ultilize o mysql_real_escape para evitar SQL Injection.